# Relevancy between two sentences in python/C++/C#/Java?

Tags: c#, java, c++, python, string

When you see the news from multiple sources, there could be chances for multiple sources(websites) might talk about same stuffs.

Is there any Python/C++/C#/Java library to compare the multiple sentences from different sources and identify the relevancy between them so that the result could be used for grouping of news?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ntlk](http://code.google.com/p/nltk/). They have a classify module for various types of classifications.

Answer (score 0):

Refer here : [Web page content analysis with "SmartBrowser"](http://msug.vn.ua/Posts/Details/3344)
Here is an [interesting sample](http://msug.vn.ua/Services/SearchGraph?q=Brad%20pitt), but you'll need to cantact author.